# How does JPA entityManager choose Connection Pool in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 *DAO* - the ***first*** works with @Bean ***DataSource*** + ***JDBC***. ***Configuration*** is the following:

```
@Bean("dataSource")
    @Singleton
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("...");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("...");
        basicDataSource.setUsername(...);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(...);
        ...
        return basicDataSource;
    }
```

The ***second*** works with ***entityManager***. *application.properties* ***configuration*** is the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
...
```

When I starts my *Spring Boot Application* and spring initializes my *beans*, I use the ***second*** DAO to get some information from ***database***.

I am using ***second*** *DAO* -> ***entityManager*** in this case.

I expects that *entityManager* uses *configuration* from ***application.properties***.
Indeed, *entityManager* uses *configration* from bean ***DataSource***.

***How does It work?***
***p.s.*** database properties in application.properties look like used.

Actually I think that I should use one ***ConnectionPool***  for my application.
I can configure ***DataSource*** as @Bean and provide ***entityManager*** and ***jdbcTemplate*** with It.
***Should I choose another solution? Or Is this idea quite suitable?***

Comment: A JPA `EntityManager` simply uses the `DataSource` that an `EntityManagerFactory` has been defined with (assuming a datasource was provided to it). A DataSource would likely be defined FROM a ConnectionPool up front

Comment: But why does entityManager choose dataSource from @Bean, not from application.properties? I suppose that It takes it from application.properties and after from beans, otherwise i don't know why in application.properties database properties look like used.

Comment: An `EntityManager` is from the JPA spec. There is no `application.properties` in the JPA spec. Perhaps you should read up on it. What you talk of is SPRING, not JPA. SPRING defines the datasource and what it passes to JPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the importance. `@Configuration` has higher precedence than application.properties. First spring-boot searches for `@Bean` definition, if it's not found, then it checks application.properties. Generally those definitions are equivalent.